# Unable to override bootstrap styles

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, react-bootstrap

I have tried following the instructions listed on Bootstrap's website, as well as various StackOverflow questions, and am still unable to override a single style element of Bootstrap. I'd appreciate help, I'm not particularly knowledgeable of web dev.

Here is my setup.

I used create-react-app to generate a file structure. I have an index.js where I immediately `import './index.scss';`

Here is my index.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Catamaran, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }

code {
  font-family: Catamaran source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace; }

/* playfair-display-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(""), url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("./fonts/playfair-display-v25-latin-regular.svg#PlayfairDisplay") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }

/* catamaran-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Catamaran';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(""), url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("./fonts/catamaran-v8-latin-regular.svg#Catamaran") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1020px,
  xxl: 1080px
);

$blue:   #306779;
$primary: #306779;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

The fonts are loading correctly, but the bootstrap variables are not. I have also attempted to manually transpile a scss file into a css file and import that into the `<head>` using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../scss/custom.css" />`, however that also does not work and I still see the normal bootstrap color scheme.

Comment: What instructions in Bootstrap's website?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/